# JMeter: conditional path into http request

Tags: jmeter

I've created this user variables:

[image]

I'm using it, in order to build a conditional path into an Http Request:

[image]

I was expecting to request to `http://localhost:8080/userlogin`, instead of `http://localhost:8080/1/userlogin`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) default value is 1

> Unlike the __property function, there is no option to save the value in a variable, and if no default value is supplied, it is assumed to be 1

So in your case use `__property` instead